# Loopback custom remote method can't parse JSON-encoded object value

Tags: node.js, angular, loopback

I have created my custom strong-loopback end-point, that accept query condition and callback function, query condition may be a json object like `{publishDate: {$lt: new Date(Date() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 2))}}`, but remote method can't parse it.
Bellow is my remote method:

```
JobPosting.jobsByDate = function (groupByCandition, callback) {
   JobPosting.find(groupByCandition,function (err, results) {
     if (err) {
       return callback('err');
     }
     return callback(null, results.length);
   });
}


JobPosting.remoteMethod(
  'jobsByDate',
  {
    accepts: [
      {arg: 'queryCondition', type: 'json', required: true}
    ],
    returns: {root: true},

    http: {path: '/jobsByDate/:queryCondition', verb: 'get'}
});
```

But when i call it via explorer and pass `{publishDate: {$lt: new Date(Date() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 2))}}` gives error:

```
{
"error": {
"statusCode": 500,
"name": "AssertionError",
"message": "The query argument must be an object",
"actual": false,
"expected": true,
"operator": "==",
"generatedMessage": false,
"stack": "AssertionError: The query argument must be an object\n    at .....
}
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if that is the issue, but when passing an object literal as a string, the keys need to be enclosed in double quotes

Comment: @devnull69 I have checked with double quotes, but has the same problem.

Comment: Maby add `console.log(groupByCandition);` to `JobPosting.jobsByDate` and show result

Answer (score 0):

Change `type: 'json'` to `type: 'object'`. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are testing with a bad formatted **object**. In loopback, you will encounter the following error if you enter for example something like that:

```
{
  startDate : "2020-07-30T08:00:00.000Z",
  endDate :"2020-10-30T08:00:00.000Z",
  status : "BOOK_CONFIRM"
}
```

While the right format looks like this:

```
{
  "startDate" : "2020-07-30T08:00:00.000Z",
  "endDate" :"2020-10-30T08:00:00.000Z",
  "status" : "BOOK_CONFIRM"
}
```